# iptables - can't route between VPN and LAN

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, vpn, firewall

I'm using the docker image [hwdsl2/ipsec-vpn-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/hwdsl2/ipsec-vpn-server/) as my VPN server and have managed to successfully establish a connection between a remote site and this site.

---

**Site overview:**

Site 1: Using hwdsl2/ipsec-vpn-server on debian

```
WAN (Interface: ens18 behind NAT): 10.10.10.0/24 [Machine IP: 10.10.10.13]

LAN (Interface: ens19): 192.168.0.0/24  [Machine IP: 192.168.0.13]

VPN (Interface: pppx where x can be any number): inet 192.168.42.1 peer 192.168.42.10
```

Site 2:

```
LAN: 10.1.0.0/16
```

---

Site 2 can successfully ping any interface on the site 1 vpnserver (10.10.10.13 and 192.168.0.13). However, cannot connect to any other 192.168.0.0/24 device (timeout).

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get routing from site 2 working to site 1 by removing --net=host from the docker run command for the L2TP server.

Will create separate questions for the other routing issues.